# Filter Excel Column with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filter, automation

I have 5 columns but I only want the rows where column A = Override

Column A    Column B  etc...
Override      xxxx
Matrix        xxxx

What is the correct syntax to filter column A correctly?

Comment: `df[df['Colum a'] == 'Override']`

Answer (score 0):

The following will remove columns with names that are not the same as 'Override'.

```
import pandas as pd

#read in dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_df)

cols_name = df.columns.tolist()
for col in cols_name:
    if df[col] is not df['Override']:
        del df[col]
```